# SocialEngine - Hook before signup process complete

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, hook, socialengine

I want to add a new step in signup process of SocialEngine and I want after first step to send some verification code to the user's phone number. How can I set a hook for that like `onUserCreateBefore`. I added this in `User/Plugin/Core.php` but no result. When I pass step 1 that is main information about `Account` but that hook doesn't call even if I `die('something')`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party plugin for mobile verification.

https://www.ipragmatech.com/products/socialengine-mobile-verification-plugin/

Comment: I thought here we can ask programming questions, I didn't know here is somewhere to redirect users to some external sources to buy something. Anyway I want to do it myself.

Comment: take a look engine4_user_signup table and add your step.Please let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: I had added it. @gaurav

Comment: whats the issue now?